# Can i use the Pivot Control for this?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm developing a Windows Phone app. In short, the app receives a list of urls to images, and I want the user to be able to "scroll/navigate" like a "next/prev" function through the list of images. But I'm a bit unsure if I can use the Pivot Control for this. If this is possible, I probably need to create all the "pivots" through code, on the fly. Is this achcievable? Could someone please kick me in the right direction please? It's a maximum of 250 image-urls in the list that I want to make.

Answer (score 1):

I could find the source for this, but i read somewhere that a best practice is that you should have around 6-7 pivot items. I don't think max 250 items would give a smooth user experience. Also navigation within your app can be hard.

I would suggest use the swipe event to load the next image in an imagebox (kinda like the pictures in the pictures hub.), or use next/previous buttons.

Comment: I solved it by adding 5 new pivotitems when I needed them, thanks though ChristiaanV